# JSON get full digit number

Tags: json, grails

I have a BigInteger variable, e.g. `chipertext`:

```
println "chipherTotalAmount= "+chipertext
```

result :
[image]

Then I parse it to JSON, and the result was

[image]

how can I get that value with full digits?

This is my code from web app.

```
def registerItem = RegisterItem.where {
    (dateReceivedItem >= fromDate && dateReceivedItem < toDate)
}.list()

println "registerItem.size = "+registerItem.size()

for (int x = 0; x < registerItem.size(); x++){

    RSA rsa =  new RSA()
    println "x noata .clas = "+registerItem[x].noNota.class
    // BigInteger plaintext = new BigInteger( registerItem[x].noNota.getBytes())

    publickey = new BigInteger(cifuser.publicKey)
    newn = new BigInteger(cifuser.newn)
    privatekey = new BigInteger(cifuser.privateKey)

    BigInteger NoNota = new BigInteger(registerItem[x].noNota.getBytes());
    BigInteger chipherNoNota = rsa.encrypt(NoNota, publickey, newn);
    println "chipherNoNota = "+chipherNoNota

    def totalmountString = registerItem[x].totalAmount.toString()
    println "totalmountString = "+totalmountString
    println "totalmountString = "+totalmountString.class
    BigInteger TotalAmount = new BigInteger(totalmountString.getBytes());
    BigInteger chipherTotalAmount = rsa.encrypt(TotalAmount, publickey, newn);
    println "chipherTotalAmount = "+chipherTotalAmount

    BigInteger SenderName = new BigInteger(registerItem[x].senderName.getBytes());
    BigInteger chipherSenderName = rsa.encrypt(SenderName, publickey, newn);
    println "chipherSenderName = "+chipherSenderName

    registerItem[x].noNota = chipherNoNota.toString()
    registerItem[x].totalAmount = chipherTotalAmount //i cannot parse this to String because at my domain totalAmount was BigInteger
    registerItem[x].senderName = chipherSenderName.toString()
    registerItem[x].discard()
}
```

This is my domain

```
class RegisterItem implements Serializable{

    String noNota
    City destination
    Date dateReceivedItem

    String senderName
    String noTelpSender
    String noHpSender
    String emailSender
    String addressSender
    String descriptionSender

    String receiverName
    String noTlpReceiver
    String noHpReceiver
    String emailReceiver
    String addressReceiver
    String descriptionReceiver

    String deleteFlag = "N"

    BigInteger totalAmount

    String isPay = "Y"

    String useDefault = "Y"

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    String updatedBy = ""
    String createdBy

    static constraints = {
        noTelpSender(nullable:true,blank:true)
        noHpSender(nullable:true,blank:true)
        emailSender(nullable:true,blank:true)
        addressSender(nullable:true,blank:true)
        descriptionSender(nullable:true,blank:true)

        noTlpReceiver(nullable:true,blank:true)
        noHpReceiver(nullable:true,blank:true)
        emailReceiver(nullable:true,blank:true)
        addressReceiver(nullable:true,blank:true)
        descriptionReceiver(nullable:true,blank:true)

        createdBy(blank: false, maxSize: 50)
        lastUpdated(nullable: true)
    }

    def beforeInsert = {
        // createdBy = springSecurityService.principal.username
        dateCreated = new Date()
    }
    def beforeUpdate = {
        // updatedBy = springSecurityService.principal.username
        lastUpdated = new Date()
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse it to `String` instead so you will have full control of the actual result specially if its a BigInteger Type.

Comment: i cannot do that, because i parse a list domain from grails and that field totalAmount was BigInteger

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin see my post's change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you and keen on a lose-less conversion, I would parse it to `String` and send it as a `String`  using:

```
String.valueOf(bigInt);
```

or

```
bigInt.toString();
```